# Export Dynamic Jquery variable data in Excel sheet

Tags: jquery

I want to export dynamic variable data into excel sheet.
I want to export Subject and marks variable data into excel file.;

```
$("#btnSave").click(function(){
            var div = $("#outputTable");
            $("#tblSubjects tr").each(function(){
                var subject = $(this).find("#txtSubject").val();
                var marks = $(this).find("#txtMarks").val();

                div.append("Subject :" + subject + ", Marks :"+marks+",Status :" +status);
                div.append("<br>");
            });

    });
```

There are two fields I have added subject and Marks using HTML. Using Jquery function I fetched those dynamic variables from HTML input textbox and stored in variables subject and marks. whatever input I give into that textbox I want to move that variable data into excel sheet with defined row.

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: There are two fields I have added subject and Marks using HTML. Using Jquery function I fetched those dynamic variables from HTML input textbox and stored in variables subject and marks.                             whatever input I give into that textbox I want to move that variable data into excel sheet with defined row.  Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Added comment in Question, since it is part of question and you need not to add it in comment,